# java and sql showed #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE roomID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM rooms r,reservation e WHERE  r.roomID=e.roomID AND (checkout > ?) AND (check-in < ?));
```

this is the SQL string for my java program, I wanted it to filter the rooms which aren't booked during selected check-in and check-out date. but the command showed this: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s). I wonder what's the problem of it.

Comment: `SELECT *` doesn't select one column, it selects multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted it to filter the rooms which aren't booked during selected check-in and check-out date. but the command showed this:

If you want to find available rooms, I would suggest `not exists`:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM rooms r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM reservation res
                  WHERE res.roomID = r.roomID AND
                        checkin < :period_end AND
                        checkout > :period_start
                 );
```

You can use `?` for the parameters, of course.  I used `:period_start` and `:period_end` so the query is clear on how the values are being used.

Answer (score 1):

roomID is a single value. SELECT * returns every columns - i.e. more than one value. The SQL concept of `someExpr IN (SELECT ...)` works, but *only* if you select a single column.

Most likely all you need here is to replace `SELECT * FROM rooms r, reservation e`) with `SELECT r.roomID FROM...` instead.

However, this entire query is suspect. It's very inefficient and bizarre to write it this way. You already selected the relevant rooms, so..

```
SELECT r.* FROM rooms r
  LEFT JOIN reservation e ON r.roomID = e.roomID
  AND (e.checkout > ?) AND (e.checkin < ?)
  WHERE e.roomID IS NOT NULL;
```

This tries to join a reservation to your rooms table, and as it's a left outer join, if there are zero matching reservations, each reservation table's column gets a NULL value instead. So, we look for that - those'd be the rooms for which no matching reservation is found.

Comment: I didn't select for any room yet. My main objective is to use the check-in date and check-out date to find all the available rooms that are not booked between the 2 dates. And yea it is quite bizarre cause I am in a rush for my assignment hehehe

Comment: My query does exactly what you want.

Comment: or is it my entire code having a problem, it just shows me the booked room between two dates? hmmm